# Hide div with slide-to-left effect

Tags: jquery, css

I've searched for topics, with same questions, but can't find the answer.

To visualise my question - here's my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MkHE/)

I want to make calc div to slide to the left, as shown at the bottom of my example (animation and behavior are perfect). But when it slides, the whole content of the page must slide left with it too. And when it slides back it must move content to the right. The content itself behaves as it shown right now, floats it from left.

If there's simplier method to do this or any mistakes in markup - I'll accept any corrections.

Thanks in advance

Update:

Forget to mention, that when it slides from page, it must still be visible for 2-3px

Comment: I'm not sure to have correctly understend but: you can get all next div via `.nextAll()` and then animate each: `var $lefty = $(this).nextAll(); $lefty.each(function(){ $(this).animate({...`is it correct?

Comment: dou you want to slide just `<div id="calc">` or the whole page including header and footer? tell us the `div` you want to slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think my description was too complex and unclear for you, sorry for my english.
I've reached what I wanted, with `$('#calc').animate({width: 'toggle'});`

Here's result in action (updated version) [on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAAyt/)